# Eliminar espacios en blanco de los <input> de un <form>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que necesito hacer es: Eliminar los espacios en blanco de los valores de los input sin dejar de enviar todo el formulario a una función.

Lo he logrado, pero solo para un valor y necesito una forma de hacerlo para todos los inputs, y luego enviar el formulario completo pero con los valores sin espacios.

```js
$(function() {
  var datoFormatiado = $.trim($('#name').val())
  var formulario = $('#x').find($('#name').val(datoFormatiado));
  validaForm(formulario)

  function validaForm (formulario){
      console.log('imprimir el formulario con todos sus inputs sin espacios');
      console.log(formulario);
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="validar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="x" action="../form-result.php" target="_blank">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="d">
        <p>Ingresa nombre</p>
        <input id="name" value=" Jarol " class="s" type="text" placeholder="nombre" >
        <input id="clave" type="text" value=" ddd " placeholder="clave" >
      </div>
      <div class="w">
        <p>Ingresa nombre</p>
        <input id="s" class="s" value=" ddd " type="text" placeholder="Enviar la información" >
        <input type="text" value=" ddd " placeholder="Enviar cccc" >
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que tengas los siguientes inputs

```
<input type="text" value=" abc ">
<input type="text" value=" def ">
<input type="text" value=" ghi ">
```

Lo que deberias hacer es lo siguiente:

```
var inputs = $("input[type=text]");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  var aux = $(inputs[i]).val().trim();
  $(inputs[i]).val(aux);
}
```

Con esto eliminas los espacios en blanco y son asignados a sus respectivos inputs

Answer (score 7):

Lo que tienes en tu código es que solo le estás quitando los espacios en blanco a un campo específico, para hacerlo con todos debes capturarlos y recorrerlos para quitar los espacios de cada campo en cada iteración.

```js
$(function(){
  var campos = $('#x input');
    
  campos.each(function(index, campo){
    var valor = $(campo).val().trim();
    
    $(campo).val(valor);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="x" action="../form-result.php" target="_blank">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="d">
      <p>Ingresa nombre</p>
      <input id="name" value=" Jarol " class="s" type="text" placeholder="nombre" >
      <input id="clave" type="text" value=" ddd " placeholder="clave" >
    </div>
    <div class="w">
      <p>Ingresa nombre</p>
      <input id="s" class="s" value=" ddd " type="text" placeholder="Enviar la información" >
      <input type="text" value=" ddd " placeholder="Enviar cccc" >
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Saludos puedes realizar de la siguiente manera:

```js
  function eliminaEspacio(){
  
    $('input').val(function(_, value) {
       return $.trim(value);
    });

  }//end function eliminaEspacio
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="x" action="../form-result.php" target="_blank">
  <fieldset>
   <div class="d">
    <p>Ingresa nombre</p>
    <input id="name" value=" Jarol " class="s" type="text" placeholder="nombre" >
    <input id="clave" type="text" value=" ddd " placeholder="clave" >
   </div>
   <div class="w">
    <p>Ingresa nombre</p>
    <input id="s" class="s" value=" ddd " type="text" placeholder="Enviar la información" >
    <input type="text" value=" ddd " placeholder="Enviar cccc" >
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 <button type="button" onclick="eliminaEspacio();">Eliminar Espacio</button>
 </form>
```

Lo que hace basicamente es recorrer uno a uno los input para remover los espacios de todo el documento.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar el excelente aporte de Bender Paisa, le agregaría un identificador que te permita limpiar los inputs que requieras solamente. También tomar en consideración agregarlo a una función para ser ejecutado cuando lo precises.

```
$(function(){
    // función limpiar espacios en blancos la puedes colocar
    // en un archivo reutilizable y ejecutarla en diversos escenarios
    function trimClear(tag){}
        var campos = $(tag);

        campos.each(function(index, campo){
            if(this.data("trim") == "true"){
                var valor = $(campo).val().trim();
                $(campo).val(valor);
            }
        })
    }

    trimClear('#x input');
});
```

HTML Demo

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="x" action="../form-result.php" target="_blank">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="d">
      <p>Ingresa nombre</p>
      <input id="name" value=" Jarol " class="s" data-trim="true" type="text" placeholder="nombre" >
      <input id="clave" type="text" value=" ddd " placeholder="clave" >
    </div>
    <div class="w">
      <p>Ingresa nombre</p>
      <input id="s" class="s" value=" ddd " data-trim="true" type="text" placeholder="Enviar la información" >
      <input type="text" value=" ddd " placeholder="Enviar cccc" >
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Necesito imprimir todo el contenido del formulario con los ejemplos antes vistos solo puedo traer los inputs mas no todo el formulario